# Auto-submit HTML Form using VB in Access 2007

Tags: html, vba, forms, ms-access

I'm at my wit's end on this one.

Part of a project I'm working on requires interaction with an HTML form to bring up the correct page on an external web-based tool.  I've managed to make this form accept entered variables and be generated on the fly using document.write, but what I haven't been able to do reliably is trigger the 'Submit' action in a way that will not throw off Error 91.

So far, I've been using a simple getelementbyid.click call... Here's a list of a few things I've tried to get it to trigger:

```
TestLoop:
   Pause (1)
   BrowserControl.document.getelementbyid("Submit").click
   On Error Goto TestLoop
```

*(The 'Error Loop' tactic didn't really work at all.)

```
   Pause (3)
   BrowserControl.document.getelementbyid("Submit").click
```

*(This actually works the best, but because different PCs might have different hardware specs and open applications that might slow it down, what works for me hasn't been working for another tester.  If I make it TOO long, I end up adding additional delay to a form I'm already worried about being too slow.)*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
     document.getElementById('Submit').click();;
    }
</script>
```

*(Embedding an auto-trigger in the generated HTML, frustratingly, works OUTSIDE of the embedded web browser control, but not inside it.)*

```
Private Sub wb_NavigateComplete2(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)

 If Me.BrowserControl.Document.URL= "about:blank" Then
        BrowserControl.document.getelementbyid("Submit").click
 End If
End Sub
```

*(For some insane reason, using debug.print I found that it's saying the navigation is complete before it's actually complete, so this didn't work at all.)*

I may have missed a few...  I've been attacking this from a bunch of different angles.  The trick is that I have to use the HTML form to interact with this system that I don't have admin priveledges on, so changing how the information is recieved isn't really an option.

My last train of thought was to see if I could mimic a FORM submission using straight VB, bypassing the need for a 'click' event, but it's been exceptionally difficult to search for things related to HTML FORM interactions with Access 2007 Forms. :P

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does error 91 give you anything more as an error message?

Comment: My apologies, I thought Error 91 was pretty standard and didn't want to add too much additional clutter to the inital post. 

_"Object variable or With block variable not set"_

I'm taking this to mean that the 'Submit' button hadn't been drawn yet when the 'click' action was called.

Comment: I've found a solution that appears to be working, but I'm not 100% confident that it won't break again...  I split up the code that was originally all in Form_Open between Form_Open and Form_Current.  Form_Open ends with navigation of the browser control to about:blank, then Form_Current starts with the document.write code and the click action.  _So_ far, I haven't had any more Error 91's.  Does this seem like a proper fix or are there better recommendations?

Comment: Many times I've found a form's controls may not be reliably available at form open.  So I habitually defer any thing dealing with its controls to form load.  Form current happens even later, after form load.  So by then, they should all be available. I'm not positive that was the source of the problem, but your results sound promising.  :-)

Comment: Yeah...  I found out the hard way that I need to SHIFT-Enter to go to the next line without submitting the comment. XD

Comment: Thanks, @HansUp!  I little better about it now.  Still doesn't always fire off, but now it's getting to the about:blank stage and it usually just doesn't even try to document.write/click (so it's not giving an error).  To deal with that, I added a 10sec timer trigger. If it's still showing about:blank and hasn't gone to the next stage, it'll re-try the document.write/click action.  This only seems to happen if Access loses focus while the Form loads.

Might try shifting stuff back from _Current to _Load and see how it goes.  At least that's just a refinement and not an OHMYGODTHISISBROKENHELP.

Comment: Hmm. How about an error handler that waits, then tries to resume at the click action?  Maybe include a count of failed attempts to prevent it retrying forever.

Comment: If the initial document.write doesn't trigger, I've found that the reason is somewhere within the NavigateComplete2 call designed to listen for web page changes in the Browser control and act based on changes in the page's URL.  Activating the function on the Timer cycle if it doesn't autotrigger by the URL change works perfectly.

I'm at home, so I can't give any specific code from the project right now.  Any thoughts in that direction?

Comment: No, sorry, you're down in a detailed level with something I've not dealt with.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks anyway!  The habit you shared about Open/Load helped out a bit. ^^d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after 7 months of testing and thousands of activations in that time, splitting the 'work' seems to have done the trick.

Form_Open: Initialises the Browser Object and sets its address to about:blank

Form_Current: Calls a formula that 'draws' the web form using Document.Write, then enters a loop...

```
TestLoop:
   BrowserControl.document.getelementbyid("Submit").click
   On Error Goto TestLoop
```